# dsh (dancer's shell): is it possible to specify ports in config file?

Tags: unix, shell

Using *dsh* you can define the list of machines in ~/.dsh/machines.list in the form:

```
<user>@<host>
```

I'd like to have multiple hosts with different ssh ports, like this (I tried):

```
<user>@<samehost>:<onePort>
<user>@<samehost>:<anotherPort>
<user>@<samehost>:<yetAntherPort>
```

But *dsh* complains with a "Could not resolve hostname: user@samehost:onePort" for every line with the ":port".

I browsed the manual and there is no mention of "per line" port (there is just a global config), am I out of luck?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually create a **~/.ssh/config** file to specify individual options (see man ssh for more options) for every host, eg:

```
Host myserver
    HostName 127.0.0.1
    User someuser
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/some_id
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host otherserver.net
    User root
    Port 5010
```

After creating that file you may modify your **~/.dsh/machines_list** accordingly:

```
myserver
otherserver.net
```

Dsh should then work properly: dsh -a w

Comment: I think this is a good workaround (even if I'd rather have everything in the dsh config file), since I have many ports on the same host (they are ssh tunnels to other hosts) the .ssh/config would become:

Host tunneled1
    Host server
    User root
    Port <PORT1>

Host tunneled2
    Host server
    User root
    Port <PORT2>

...

Host tunneledN
    Host server
    User root
    Port <PORTN>

Answer (score 0):

> dsh (dancer's shell): is it possible to specify ports in config file?

As far as I have tried, I'm afraid that the answer is: No.

Use [pssh](http://www.theether.org/pssh/) instead.

**machines.pssh**

```
localhost testuser
192.168.5.141:2317 quanta
```

then try something like this:

```
parallel-ssh -P -h machines.pssh w
```